# listar publicações de amigos

Tags: php, html, mysqli

eu estou fazendo uma consulta no banco de dados para listar as minhas publicações e a das pessoas que eu sigo na minha timeline, mais a consulta apenas esta trazendo as minhas publicações.

```
<?php

$tipo_news = "SELECT * FROM $table_post WHERE usuario=$cod_login order by codigo desc";
$tipo_news_resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli, $tipo_news);
$tipo_news_quantidade = mysqli_num_rows($tipo_news_resultado);
            
$consulta_contatos = "SELECT * FROM $table_contatos WHERE usuario=$cod_login || amigo=$cod_login";
$resultado_contatos = mysqli_query($mysqli, $consulta_contatos);
$quantidade_contatos = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_contatos);

for($i=0;$i < $tipo_news_quantidade;$i++)
{
$vetor_news = mysqli_fetch_array($tipo_news_resultado);




?>
<?php print($vetor_news['nickname']); ?>
<?php print($vetor_news['post']); ?>

 <?php
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

se entendi certo deveria ser SQL mais ou menos assim :

buscar IDs dos meus contatos:

`$contatos_ids_query = "SELECT id FROM $table_contatos WHERE usuario=$cod_login";`
`$lista_ids = mysqli_query($mysqli, $contatos_ids_query);`

Transformar array com IDs em string

`$string_ids = implode(',', (array)$lista_ids);`

buscar postagens dos meus contatos:

`$contatos_news_query = "SELECT * FROM $table_post WHERE usuario in($string_ids) order by codigo desc";`

`$contatos_news = mysqli_query($mysqli, $contatos_news_query);`

`var_dump($contatos_news)`

Comment: oi, obrigado pela ajuda eu tentei fazer dessa forma e deu erro, vou tentar explicar melhor a pergunta, eu estou fazendo uma consulta no banco de dados para listar as minhas publicações e a das pessoas que eu sigo na minha timeline, mais a consulta apenas esta trazendo as minhas publicações.

Comment: Tem como mostra o erro?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: implode(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type ?array, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\social\usuario.php:650 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\social\usuario.php(650): implode(',', 'SELECT codigo F...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\social\usuario.php on line 650

Comment: Transforme $contatos_ids em array,

$string_ids = implode(',', (array) $contatos_ids);

Comment: confira se  contatos_ids está retornando um objeto com lista de id dos contatos se positivo transforme em array 

$string_ids = implode(',',  (array) $contatos_ids)

Comment: calma ai, eu reparei que tu atropelou alguns passos, tu jogou o SQL direto no $contatos_ids, isso é apenas um modelo para seguir a lógica

Comment: precisa por SQL do $contatos_ids em mysqli_query()
 mysqli_query(contatos_ids)

Comment: desculpa eu não sei fazer dessa forma.

Comment: Vou melhorar a resposta acima

Comment: Coloquei mais detalhes na resposta tenta agora.

Comment: deu erro no for. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "for" in C:\xampp\htdocs\social\usuario.php on line 663